# Is type #seq<string> option necessary?

Tags: f#

I found one parameter of a legacy code has the type of

```
#seq<string> option
```

and the parameter is used as

```
for k,v in defaultHeaders |> Seq.filter(fun (k,_) -> 
    match headers with 
    | Some hs -> not(Seq.exists(fun y -> fst y = k) hs)
    | None -> true
    ) do
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(k, v)
```

It can just use `Seq.empty` for the `None` of the parameter in the code. Is there any valid use case of type `#seq<string> option`? What's the `#` means in the type information btw?

Comment: Could you show us the function declaration line of that function (e.g., the `let fun param1 param2 = ...` or `member this.SomeMethod` line)? That might help us explain why the `option` is necessary (or why it's *not* necessary): the reason for the `option` might depend on how the function is declared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Why have a `seq option` parameter?

One possible reason for an `option` type in a parameter is [optional parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/parameters-and-arguments#optional-parameters) in a non-curried (i.e., tuple-style) method. If you have a parameter declared as `?param`, then it will be of type `Foo option` where Foo is the "normal" type of `param` (that is, the type it would have been if it wasn't an optional parameter). This allows you to write code like the following (example copied verbatim from the MSDN docs):

```
type DuplexType =
    | Full
    | Half

type Connection(?rate0 : int, ?duplex0 : DuplexType, ?parity0 : bool) =
    let duplex = defaultArg duplex0 Full
    let parity = defaultArg parity0 false
    let mutable rate = match rate0 with
                        | Some rate1 -> rate1
                        | None -> match duplex with
                                  | Full -> 9600
                                  | Half -> 4800
    do printfn "Baud Rate: %d Duplex: %A Parity: %b" rate duplex parity

let conn1 = Connection(duplex0 = Full)
let conn2 = Connection(duplex0 = Half)
let conn3 = Connection(300, Half, true)
```

Here the optional parameters are in the constructor of the `Connection` type, but you can see how they work. As for your specific question about `seq option` parameters, I'll have to tweak the MSDN docs example a little to demonstrate the difference. If one of those optional parameters had been a sequence (say, a sequence of ints representing preferred rates and fallback rates), then here's what that might look like with and without optional parameters:

```
type Connection(?rates : seq<int>) = // Final type will be `seq<int> option`
    let realRates = defaultArg rates Seq.empty
    let chosenRate = realRates |> Seq.find (fun r -> ...)

type ConnectionB(rates : seq<int>) = // Final type will be `seq<int>`
    let chosenRate = rates |> Seq.find (fun r -> ...)

let conn1 = Connection()  // Equivalent to passing `Seq.empty`
let conn2 = Connection(Seq.empty)
let conn3 = ConnectionB() // Compiler error; this is not allowed
let conn4 = ConnectionB(Seq.empty)
```

Using an optional parameter for a seq allows the caller to skip specifying that parameter, which can in some cases make your API nicer to use. So that can be one reason to use a `seq option` in a parameter. Other times it doesn't make sense; it all depends on how you want your API to look to outside code.

### What about the `#` in the type declaration?

As for your question about the `#` character, that's called [flexible types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/flexible-types) in the MSDN documentation, and it's shorthand for a type constraint: a type declaraion of `#Foo` is the same as declaring the type as `'T when 'T :> Foo`. The specific advantage of using `#seq` is that F# normally doesn't implicitly auto-cast between compatible types, and requires an explicit cast for situations like the following (again, example taken verbatim from MSDN docs):

```
let iterate1 (f : unit -> seq<int>) =
    for e in f() do printfn "%d" e
let iterate2 (f : unit -> #seq<int>) =
    for e in f() do printfn "%d" e

// Passing a function that takes a list requires a cast.
iterate1 (fun () -> [1] :> seq<int>)

// Passing a function that takes a list to the version that specifies a
// flexible type as the return value is OK as is.
iterate2 (fun () -> [1])
```

Comment: As for the `#` in the type declaration, is there any way to declare a type which accepts the derived type? Is it similar to covariance in C#? How about contravariance?

Comment: From the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/flexible-types documentation: "In F#, as in other object-oriented languages, there are contexts in which derived types or types that implement interfaces are automatically converted to a base type or interface type. These automatic conversions occur in direct arguments, but not when the type is in a subordinate position, as part of a more complex type such as a return type of a function type, or as a type argument." For those situations, you can use the `#Foo` notation.

Comment: So that's similar to covariance. As for contravariance, F# doesn't allow it to the best of my knowledge. But in practice, F# programmers rarely use covariance or contravariance because those are most useful in class hierarchies, and idiomatic F# code tends to use discriminated unions instead to model their data.

Comment: For example, see [this Reddit discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/fsharp/comments/lhx30/is_the_lack_of_covariance_in_f_as_big_a_problem/) where Jon Harrop (whose Reddit name is jdh30) said, "I've been writing code professionally in F# for 5 years now and I've only found a couple of situations where covariance might have helped and none where contravariance would have done."